# Image Scroll inside ImageView

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

So i have an image with dimensions of 6720x280, i want to put this image in the ImageView with dimensions of 280x280 and be able to scroll it on imageview touch (it is a product image, so basically i want to rotate the image inside the ImageView). So every time user drags `ImageView` image should rotate by 280px.

**Here is a process of obtaining image:**

1. Image is stored on the web server
2. User accesses product page
3. Script pre-loads the image from the server and saves it to assets folder
4. Using `InputStream` im opening image from assets folder
5. Converting it to `Drawable`
6. Updating `ImageView` with `setImageDrawable`

Since i'm new to android development, i don't know on how to approach this problem. So that's why i'm asking for help (at least, please, point me to the right direction), any help is really appreciated.

Thank you for your attention

**P.S. Here is how it should look like:**
[image]

This is how am i doing in HTML:

```
<div class="product_viewer" style="background-image: url('/assets/products/product_id.jpg'); background-position: -2800px 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotating the image? Do you want to actually rotate the image or scroll to see the invisible parts of the image?

Comment: I will update post with diagram of what im trying to achieve in 5 minutes (drawing it now)

Comment: Have you tried loading the image in a WebView?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie in android development too, but may be using a scrollview can help you. You can use addView method to add an imageview into a scrollview as i understood. Here is the developer guide for scrollview
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html
I hope it helps.